# Android. Making the screen go black

Tags: android

I'm developing a small game for Android devices. After each game is over, the opponent has the ability to start a new game at which point i clear all the bitmaps on the screen, clear all the `ImageViews` that hold the bitmaps as well and then redraw everything. The problem is that  for a second or so, the `ImageViews` which i clear disappear and then reappear after i redraw them. I would like to make the screen black or fade the entire screen to black, remove the objects, redraw/reposition them and then un-black the screen :)

How can this be accomplished? I haven't managed to find anything good out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put some overlay linearLayout and show that when necessary.

```
android:visibility="visible"
android:visibility="invisible"
```

Comment: ooh... right. Hide the entire Layout. hmm. that should work. I'll try it right now.